# How to to insert and retrieve data in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have written an app where i have to insert its data into sqlite database and show it on one activity. But my code is showing "No record Found" even if i have inserted it.

I have tried using different options like moving cursor first to the first record and then using loop iterate over the record.

Inserting data into database

```
private void saveToDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = new ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_NAME, name.getText().toString());
        values.put(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_AGE, age.getText().toString());
        values.put(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_DOB, dob.getText().toString());
        values.put(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_HEIGHT, height.getText().toString());
        values.put(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_WEIGHT, weight.getText().toString());
        database.insert(ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        database.close();   
    }
```

Retrieving data from database

```
public ArrayList<Child> readFromDB()
    {
        ArrayList<Child> List = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = new ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_TABLE_NAME, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Child child = new Child(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_NAME")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_AGE")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_DOB")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_HEIGHT")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_WEIGHT")));
            List.add(child);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return List;
    }
```

It should display the record entered but it is making the toast "No Record found".

Comment: You should use Room Persistence Library which is an ORM wrapper over SQLite instead of directly using SQLite. See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM and read this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room It is less error prone and easier to use. Also read here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Child child = new Child(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_NAME")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_AGE")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_DOB")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_HEIGHT")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_WEIGHT")));
            List.add(child);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return List;
```

Can you try this code and see it if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public ArrayList<Child> readFromDB() 
   {
  List list = new ArrayList<Child>(); 
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + 
  ChildMonitoringAppDBHelper.CHILD_TABLE_NAME, null);
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 
  if (cursor.moveToFirst())
  {  
  do
  {
 Child child = new Child(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_NAME")), 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_AGE")), 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_DOB")), 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_HEIGHT")), 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_WEIGHT")));

 list.add(child);
 } 
 while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
cursor.close(); 
// return list of inserted values
return list; 
}
```